# Not receiving temporary password emails from Cognito when used with SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have setup cognito user pool along with my custom email id. When I configure my user pool so that cognito sends email with temporary passcode(as shown in image) I can see the user receiving email from my configured custom email-id.
[image]

But when I use SES, I do not receive email.
I would like to point out that user pool is in ap-south-1 region, where as I am using SES from us-east-1 region (SES is not available in ap-south-1 region).

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue. But the emails delivery got delayed by several hours !!
Delay was happening only to email ids of certain domains and emails were getting delivered instantly to gmail.